# "All there is to it is" or "all there is to it are"?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if it's always singular. In this particular set phrase, we use the singular, but if "all there is" is actually a plural thing I wonder if we then use "are" instead of "is".

Example:

> All there is to it are these fundamental rules no one want to talk
>   about.

Comment: Can you give us more context and/or explain the situation you're trying to describe? I'm not sure this is a natural way to say what you want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that Google Books has [no written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all%20there%20are%20to%20it%22) of *all there **are** to it*. What this means to me is that *all there **is** to it* is effectively a "frozen form" - so effectively we're stuck with it regardless of whether the referent is singular or plural. There are actually only five different instances of (*some plural noun) [**are** all there is to it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are%20all%20there%20is%20to%20it%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNRvw9Jxo4_HGbOcvrZLYg1ah2xpeQ:1575036305122&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWjea7y4_mAhVCrHEKHaXZBoMQpwUIIQ&biw=1689&bih=910&dpr=1)*, so I'll list them all...

> 1: *Group standards are all there is to it*
>    2: *Two simple rectangles ... both worked diagonally, are all there is to it*
>    3:n *Perhaps my patterns are all there is to it*
>    4: *The token-reflexive facts of spatial tense given in chapter 4 are all there is to it*
>    5: *The old ships that have been gotten rid of are all there is to it*

By comparison, there are hundreds (maybe *thousands*) of instances of *(singular noun) [**is** all there is to it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20all%20there%20is%20to%20it%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNRQWjlvorqVBoBo3zcRtZpPV7WjvQ:1575036619175&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4scbRzI_mAhUVShUIHTh2AUEQpwUIIQ&biw=1689&bih=910&dpr=1)*. Obviously in practice it's more *likely* in the real world that the referent will be singular anyway, since the expression itself implies something ***small*** *(**less** in number, size, importance, etc.).* But I'm not convinced this fully accounts for the huge disparity in "number of recorded instances".

Cutting to the chase, I think most native speakers are fully aware that *all there **are** to it* is an inherently "unusual, marked" alternative to the idiomatic standard *all there **is** to it*. So they tend to avoid it even in contexts where this leads to an obvious clash between singular verb and plural subject.

---

TL;DR: Stick with the established idiomatic form *all there **is** to it* and ignore the singular/plural clash. That's what most native speakers usually do.